# How to add a Foreginkey field in signup form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a signup form.I have inherited signup class.would like to add a selection list(foregin key).am geting error.

model.py

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    status = (
        ('active', 'Active'),
        ('shutdown', 'Shutdown'),
        ('opensoon', 'Opening Soon'),
    )
    branch_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    availablity_status = models.CharField(choices=status, default='available', max_length=13 )
    branch_state = models.CharField(max_length=20, name='State')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.branch_name
```

form.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    branch_name = forms.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','branch_name','password1','password2')
        widgets = {
         'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 15, 'placeholder':     'Username'})
    }
```

Error:

```
 branch_name = forms.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 AttributeError: module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'ForeignKey'
```

Comment: The related form field is a `ModelChoiceField`. But it is rather strange that you model it this way. Looks like by adding a one-to-many relation to `User`, you can solve this more elegantly.

Comment: Hi Marcell - Willem is 100% correct, which ever method you use please ensure you have perhaps another model Employee or similar which inherits from User. Such that you can SignUp a user as well as handle the branch_name attribute in another model for Employee (I’m assuming Employee would be a suitable name for this extended User model).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**:

For this specific query, you'll need to use a `ModelChoiceField` as follows, remembering to pass in the query set for the objects you wish your user to select from.

So, I would modify your `forms.py` to:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    ...
    branch_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Branch.objects.all())
    ...
```

...or if you need multiple branches to be selected:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    ...
    branch_name = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = Branch.objects.all())
    ...
```

---

**Optional Pro-Tip**, *extending* the `ModelChoiceField`:

You may even add in the following if you don't want to display just the PrimaryKey/ID (`pk`) of the `Branch` model (rather, returning the `branch_name`):

`fields.py`:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class MyBranchModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "Branch: #%i" % obj.branch_name
```

Then use similar to above:

```
branch_name = forms.MyBranchModelChoiceField(queryset = Branch.objects.all())
```

Comment: I should caveat this by saying to make this work on UserSignUp you’ll need a OneToOne field in either the Branch model or User model which links the two.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
   branch_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Branch.objects.all())

  class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ('username','branch_name','password1','password2')
      widgets = {
         'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 15, 'placeholder':     'Username'})
    }
```

you can also do like that for select drop-down or in normal it will give value as a primary key and label what you return, in value if you need name of Branch or other detail you can also use second

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
       branch_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(o.id, str(o)) for o in Branch.objects.all()])

      class Meta:
          model = User
          fields = ('username','branch_name','password1','password2')
          widgets = {
             'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 15, 'placeholder':     'Username'})
        }
```

Comment: I’ll upvote this because I like your second method of allowing a section of the display field (perhaps more elegant than my method of extending the ModelChoiceField?) :)